# Adding LAS files into AutoCAD map 3D with Point Cloud Manager tool

Tags: 3d, import, lidar, autocad, las

It's my first time to use AutoCAD map 3D for LiDAR. Based on my googling, it is said that I can bring .las file by creating new index and using the Point Cloud Manager tool (the image on the top - [reference](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad-map-3d/learn-explore/caas/video/youtube/watch-v-4RT3Z8OHEzY.html).)).

[image: Bringing LiDAR in AutoCAD Map 3D - tutorial]

However, my AutoCAD does not show the same interface as shown in the video (the image at the bottom). I was not sure because it is a trial version. Any advice?

[image: My AutoCAD map 3D]

Answer (score 2):

Using AutoCAD Map 3D 2015
You need to create an index file for the .las file with coordinate system set.

You might need to switch from 2D to 3D mode to have the .las rendered

[image]

This styled using the elevation style

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I did not want to install the 2015 version, since it requires older version of .NET which would not cooperate with the other applications I have. However, I found the way I can open the Point Cloud Manager tool. I typed "MAPPOINTCLOUDMANAGER" in the command box, and it popped up.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the developer of the applications mentioned below.

---

If you you need to import a LAZ/LAS point cloud into AutoCAD you should check out the `LAStoDXFPointCloud` tool found at http://lidarwidgets.com

It can work on a single file or batch convert an entire folder of LIDAR files (binary compressed or uncompressed) to DXF point clouds.

If you need a true 3D vector model of the terrain surface, there's another tool there that will generate the terrain quickly too.  It's called `LAStoDXFMesh`.

There are some videos of the software in action here:  https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCpKRoJA-KbSouwC5DqgAl1A